# Competing risk regression with R

Tags: r, risk-analysis

I am trying to run a competing risk with the cmprsk package but keep getting errors. The last one that I can not solve is this one:

```
Error in solve.default(h, z[[2]]) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.7676e-34
```

here is the code I used.

`crr.matrix <- model.matrix(~ a + b + c + d + e -1, data=mydata)
crr(HV_pT1$time,HV_pT1$status,crr.matrix,failcode=2)`

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when asking for help. There's likely some problem with your data, but without knowing what the data is, it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but this may be of help to others.

I suspect the issue is with the `-1` after the e.

A  `[,-1]` is required **after** the covariates. Perhaps this is what you were aiming for with the `-1`?.
The `[,-1]` removes the constant term from the output of model.matrix e.g.

`crr.matrix <- model.matrix(~ a + b + c + d + e, data=mydata)[,-1]`.

It is sensible to also add a `cencode = y` after the `failcode = x` term.